# How to retrieve data from Array of Object in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling rest service, based on regInventoryId i want to display data that are associated with the array of object i was able to display some objects but some i could not ,From code below for example i could not populate data in the view for SubpartId. Please let me know what i am doing wrong any suggetion will be welcome.

See code Below tried so far...

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5>
                <strong>Rule Id</strong>
            </h5>
            <div>{{lrrDetail.ruleIdentifier}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5>
                <strong>SubpartID</strong>
            </h5>
            <div>{{lrrDetail.subPartId}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="modalHr"></hr>
    <div class="row lrrDetailboxMrgn">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5>
                <strong>Rule Internal or Outsourced</strong>
            </h5>
            <div>Rule internal data</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5>
                <strong>Subpart Internal or Outsourced</strong>
            </h5>
            <div>LRR Data one lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CTRL.JS

```
  $scope.lrrDetailWinOptions = lrrSearchGridConfig.modalLrrConfig;
    $scope.showDetail = function (id){
      $scope.selectedId = id;
      lrrDetails.findlrrDetail(id.regInventoryId).then(function(response){
        $scope.lrrDetail = response.data;
        $scope.$broadcast('openDetailWindow');
      });

    }
```

FACTORY.JS

```
  findlrrDetail: function(regInventoryId){
        return $http.get('/third-party-management/rest/lrr/' + regInventoryId);
    },

};
```

JSON.JS

```
0: {subPartId: "99996", regInventoryId: 38468, citationId: "94181", coreCitationId: "69502",…}
assigned: false
citationId: "94181"
citationValue: "New Jersey Statutes 46"
coreCitationId: "69502"
issuingAuth: "New Jersey Legislature"
regInventoryId: 38468
regInvetoryName: "Document Signing & Notary"
regInvetoryNameKey: 4074
regionName: "United States,"
ruleIdentifier: "17181"
ruleName: "Property"
subPartId: "99996"
subPartRuleInvortyKey: null
subpartCitation: "New Jersey Statutes 46:14-6.1"
subpartRuleName: null
```

JSON1.JS

```
applicabilityIndicator: "0"
auditGroupCategory: null
auditGroupIndicator: "0"
citationAsOfDate: 1385355600000
citationCoreIndicator: "69498"
citationValue: "New Jersey Statutes 46"
createdBy: "ERDSYSTEM"
createdDate: 1387240599333
enterpriseReportingHierarchies: []
externalIndintifier: "94177"
geographicLocations: [{id: 5670, sourceFeedKey: 5, lookupCode: "RS_ACTIVE", externalIndintifier: "226",…}]
0: {id: 5670, sourceFeedKey: 5, lookupCode: "RS_ACTIVE", externalIndintifier: "226",…}
highValueSummary: "Title 46 of the New Jersey statutes provides property laws."
id: 38468
issuingAuthority: {id: 13853, agencyCode: "NJ Leg", agencyName: "New Jersey Legislature",…}
agencyCode: "NJ Leg"
agencyName: "New Jersey Legislature"
id: 13853
issuingAuthName: "New Jersey Legislature"
lookupCode: "RS_ACTIVE"
modifiedDate: 1421072858363
mofifiedBy: "ERDSYSTEM"
regInventoryRuleSubPart: null
regulatoryInventoryClassfication: {id: 8001, classificationName: "Compliance", sponserWrokerKey: 209161}
classificationName: "Compliance"
id: 8001
sponserWrokerKey: 209161
regulatoryInventoryName: {id: 4074, inventoryName: "Document Signing & Notary", erhKey: 17844, regInvetoryclassKey: 8001}
erhKey: 17844
id: 4074
inventoryName: "Document Signing & Notary"
regInvetoryclassKey: 8001
ruleIdentifier: "17181"
ruleName: "Property"
sourceFeedKey: 15
subpartCitationCount: 4
subpartCitationIndicator: "0"
subpartCount: 4
vedourActivityDescription1: null
vedourActivityDescription2: null
vedourActivityType: "Both"
```

Comment: is your data object an array? I see the index 0 in the json

Comment: try: `$scope.lrrDetail = response.data[0];`

Comment: actually, I don't think you need the `data` part. only `$scope.lrrDetails = reponse` will resolve I think. or `response[0]` if the response is an array. But this is valid only when you use `$resource` to communicate with server

Comment: Ah forget about this last comment, you dont need the data when you are using the `$resource` service. Using `$http` you will need the `data` attribute

Comment: Did you template are configured to respond to this controller? And this JSON, is the one that you receive in response.data?

Comment: i have edit my question so here may be i can explain better when i call rest service i get JSON1.JS response , now i want to display data for id that is regInventoryId in JSON.JS , how i can retrieve JSON.JS data that is associated with regInventoryId 38468.

Comment: Your JSON1.JS is literally what you receive? It's not wrapped in {}?

Comment: that is understood..but my JSON1.JS id:38468 and regInventoryId:38468 JSON.JS are the same object to make associations between JSON responses .. i just want to understand can we display data based on these ids or not.. OR i have to get json response first anything i am displayign in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you do a lot of this type of find-then-filter type of operations, you should checkout Underscore.js. It's a super useful library. Then you can use it's `_.findWhere()` function like so (i'm calling your json.js array `json1` for clarity):

```
$scope.lrrDetailWinOptions = lrrSearchGridConfig.modalLrrConfig;
  $scope.showDetail = function (id){
    $scope.selectedId = id;
      lrrDetails.findlrrDetail(id.regInventoryId).then(function(response){
      $scope.json2 = response.data;
      $scope.lrrDetail = _.findWhere($scope.json1, {'regInventoryId':$scope.json2.id});
      $scope.$broadcast('openDetailWindow');
  });
}
```

This will return the first match in the json1 array. Now the syntax to get the correct value from json2 array might be different for you, but just experiment with `console.log(response.data)` until you find the value you're looking for. For example, you could try like. `console.log(response.data[0].id);`

Comment: Thanks alot to give me suggetion!